# SwiftUI: Instance member 'enableFilter' cannot be used on type 'ContentView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-state

I'm a beginner with SwiftUI and I wanted to create a dynamic list with the birthdays of people. I also wanted to integrate a filter that facilitates to find birthdays. But in the lines:

```
if enableFilter == true {
    return json.filter {$0.BirthdayString.contains(filter(date: filterDate))}
} else {
   return json
}
```

I always get these errors:

> Instance member 'enableFilter' cannot be used on type 'ContentView';
> did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

and

> Instance member 'filterDate' cannot be used on type 'ContentView'; did
> you mean to use a value of this type instead?

I think I understand why the errors are present but I don't no how to fix it. I tried:

```
@State static var
```

but then I cannot change the values with my

```
filterView
```

Thank you for your help, here is the full source code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct person: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var Birthday: Date
    var BirthdayString: String
}

func filter(date: Date) -> String {
    let DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
   let DateComponentsString: String = "\(DateComponents.day)/\(DateComponents.month)/\(DateComponents.year)"
    
    return DateComponentsString
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var people: [person] = {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "people") else { return [] }
        if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode([person].self, from: data) {
            if enableFilter == true {
                return json.filter {$0.BirthdayString.contains(filter(date: filterDate))}
            } else {
                return json
            }
        }
        return []
    }()

@State var filterDate: Date = Date()
@State var enableFilter: Bool = false

@State var showFilter: Bool = false
@State var newPersonDate: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    DatePicker(selection: $newPersonDate, label: {Text("Birthday")}).padding()
                    
                    Button(action: {didTapAddTask()}, label: {Text("Add")}).padding()
                }
                
            List {
                ForEach($people) { $person in
                    Text("\(person.Birthday)")
                }
            }
        }
            .navigationTitle(Text("People's birthday"))
        }
    }
    
    var filterView: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker(selection: $filterDate, label: {Text("Date")}).padding()
            Toggle(isOn: $enableFilter, label: {Text("enable filter")}).padding()
        }
    }
    
    func didTapAddTask() {
    let id = people.reduce(0) { max($0, $1.id) } + 1
    people.insert(person(id: id, Birthday: newPersonDate, BirthdayString: filter(date: newPersonDate)), at: 0)
    newPersonDate = Date()
    save()
    }
                                                 
    func save() {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(people) else { return }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "people")
    }
    }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) There is a lot wrong with what you are trying to do. SwiftUI does not work as you are expecting it to. Computed properties don’t work with wrappers and per the error trying to change variables by holding on to a view object in a variable is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another Computed property which will get the data based on some another property's value. i.e `enableFilter`.

```
@State var people: [person]  = {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "people") else { return [] }
        if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode([person].self, from: data) {
            return json
        }
        return []
}()

var data : [person] {
    if enableFilter {
        return people.filter {$0.BirthdayString.contains(filter(date: filterDate))}
    } else {
        return people
    }
}
```

And use this property to get the relevant data:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                DatePicker(selection: $newPersonDate, label: {Text("Birthday")}).padding()
                Button(action: {didTapAddTask()}, label: {Text("Add")}).padding()
            }
        List {
            ForEach(data) { person in   // <<--- Here `data`
                Text("\(person.Birthday)")
            }
        }
    }
        .navigationTitle(Text("People's birthday"))
    }
}
```